# Is it possible to let each other iOS devices is nearby?

Tags: ibeacon

I want to make a game .
There are 20 iPhones or more.
When one iPhone is nearly another.they both know that. (Distance is less than 1or 2 meters)
Is it possible?
sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible, but only if phones have your app in the foreground.**

Apps can send an iBeacon transmission, but only if they are in the foreground.  Apps listening for an iBeacon transmission can do so both in the background and foreground, allowing other apps that are up to ~40 meters away to know about the presence of the transmitting apps.